# How to access SessionFactory of Hibernate using JNDI in WEBLOGIC 9.2 server?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, weblogic

We are using Weblogoic9.2.3 & DB is Oracle10.2.0.3.
How can we access Hibernate SessionFactory using JNDI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd warmly suggest to read the chapter [3.8. J2EE Application Server integration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-j2ee) of the documentation. But With Weblogic 9.x and Oracle 10g, you'll end up with something like this (partial but tested setup):

```
...
<property name="hibernate.session_factory_name">hibernate.SessionFactory</property> <!-- JNDI bound Session Factory Name -->
<property name="hibernate.jndi.url">t3://localhost:port</property>
<property name="hibernate.jndi.class">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.jndi.weblogic.jndi.replicateBindings">false</property> <!-- because SessionFactory is not clusterable -->
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
...
```