# Strange hibernate error in weblogic(10.3.4) console

Tags: hibernate, jsf-2, ejb-3.0, primefaces, weblogic-10.x

I have followgin configuration files, and I got following exception while getting Hibernate session. Is there a problem or missing property in hibernate.cfg.xml?

persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<jta-data-source>test-ds</jta-data-source>

 <properties>
    <property name="hibernate.jndi.url" value="t3://127.0.0.1:7001" />
    <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="test-ds" />
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.WeblogicTransactionManagerLookup" />
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="jta" />
</properties>

<!-- For WebLogic AppSer. -->
<class>test.model.BaseEntity</class>
<class>test.model.InvoiceDetail</class>
<class>test.model.InvoiceMovement</class>
<class>test.model.InvoicePaymentItem</class>
<class>test.model.Job</class>
<class>test.model.Member</class>

</persistence-unit>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                     "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"><hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.jndi.url">t3://127.0.0.1:7001</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">test-ds</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.WeblogicTransactionManagerLookup</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</property>

    <mapping class="test.model.BaseEntity" />
    <mapping class="test.model.InvoiceDetail" />
    <mapping class="test.model.InvoiceMovement" />
    <mapping class="test.model.InvoicePaymentItem" />
    <mapping class="test.model.Job" />
    <mapping class="test.model.Member" />
</session-factory>
```

I've also added the classpath jpa2.0 jars in weblogic configuration file and created a datasource named test-ds and jndi name named test-ds via weblogic admin console. I assembled the all model operations methods into the class ModelOperations. The header of the class is the following:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class ModelOperations implements ModelOperationsLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "beyazfatura")
    private EntityManager em;  
...
```

In this class I have a method stated below:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Member> getMembers(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
        String sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters, Date beginDate,
        Date endDate) {
    Session session = null;
    List<Member> memberList = null;
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Member.class);

        Criterion betweenDate = null;
        if (beginDate != null) {
            if (endDate == null) {
                endDate = new Date();// now
            }
            betweenDate = Restrictions.between("createTime", beginDate,
                    endDate);
        }

        if (betweenDate != null) {
            crit.add(betweenDate);
        }

       // sorting
        if (sortField != null && !sortField.isEmpty()) {
            if (!sortOrder.equalsIgnoreCase("UNSORTED")) {
                if (sortOrder.equalsIgnoreCase("ASCENDING")) {
                    crit = crit.addOrder(Order.asc(sortField));
                } else {
                    crit = crit.addOrder(Order.desc(sortField));
                }
            }
        }

        // filtering
        if (filters != null && !filters.isEmpty()) {
            Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = filters.entrySet().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Entry<String, String> entry = iterator.next();
                Class<?> type = Member.class.getDeclaredField(
                        entry.getKey()).getType();
                try {
                    if (type.isEnum()
                            || Number.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
                        crit = crit.add(Restrictions.eq(
                                entry.getKey(),
                                type.getDeclaredMethod("valueOf",
                                String.class).invoke(null,
                                entry.getValue())));
                    } else {
                        crit = crit.add(Restrictions.like(entry.getKey(),
                                entry.getValue(), MatchMode.START));
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // Aim: return the list anyway.
                    LOG.warn(ex, ex);
                }
            }
        }

        if (first != -1) {
            crit = crit.setFirstResult(first);
        }

        if (pageSize != -1) {
            crit = crit.setMaxResults(pageSize);
        }

        memberList = crit.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e, e);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

    return memberList;
}

@Override
public Long getMemberCount(Date beginDate, Date endDate) {
    Session session = null;
    Long returnValue = 0L;
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Member.class);

        Criterion betweenDate = null;
        if (beginDate != null) {
            if (endDate == null) {
                endDate = new Date();// now
            }
            betweenDate = Restrictions.between("createTime", beginDate,
                    endDate);
        }

        if (betweenDate != null) {
            crit.add(betweenDate);
        }

        crit.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
        if(crit.list() != null){
            returnValue = (Long) crit.list().get(0);
        } else {
            returnValue = 0L;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e, e);
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

and this is the HibernateUtil class:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(HibernateUtil.class);
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            LOG.error(e, e);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

I call getMember and getMemberCount method from a backing bean(of a datatable). I annotated the modeloperations class in the backing-bean. In order to use @EJB annotation, I deploy the jsf2.war as a libray in weblogic. The header of the managed bean and the LazyDataModel are below:

Backing-bean header:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "memberManagement")
@SessionScoped
public class MemberManagement {

    @EJB
    private ModelOperationsLocal modelOperations;
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MemberManagement.class);
    private MemberLazyDataModel memberModel;  

    @PostConstruct
    public void initModel() {
        memberModel = new MemberLazyDataModel(pageSize, beginDate, endDate,
            modelOperations);
    }
```

LazyDataModel

```
public class MemberLazyDataModel extends LazyDataModel<Member> {

    private ModelOperationsLocal modelOperations;
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MemberLazyDataModel.class);
    private int pageSize;
    private Date beginDate;
    private Date endDate;

    public MemberLazyDataModel() {
    }

    public MemberLazyDataModel(int pageSize, Date beginDate, Date endDate,
        ModelOperationsLocal modelOperations) {
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
        this.beginDate = beginDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.modelOperations = modelOperations;
        super.setPageSize(pageSize);
        super.setRowCount(modelOperations.getMemberCount(beginDate, endDate).intValue());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Member> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
        SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {
        super.setRowCount(modelOperations.getMemberCount(beginDate, endDate).intValue());
        return modelOperations.getMembers(first, pageSize, sortField,
            sortOrder.name(), filters, beginDate, endDate);
    }

    @Override
    public String getRowKey(Member member) {
        return member.getId() + "";
    }

    @Override
    public Member getRowData(String rowKey) {

        List<Member> members = (List<Member>) getWrappedData();

        for (Member member : members) {
            if ((member.getId() + "").equals(rowKey)) {
                return member;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

When I click the page which includes the member datatable I get the following exception(as if it gets the hibernate.cfg.xml first time???):

```
INFO  Configuration                   - configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
INFO  Configuration                   - Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
INFO  Configuration                   - Configured SessionFactory: null
```

some table binding logs then the below logs and the exception:

```
INFO  TransactionFactoryFactory       - Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
INFO  ransactionManagerLookupFactory  - instantiating TransactionManagerLookup: org.hibernate.transaction.WeblogicTransactionManagerLookup
INFO  ransactionManagerLookupFactory  - instantiated TransactionManagerLookup
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - JDBC batch size: 15
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - Scrollable result sets: enabled
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - Connection release mode: auto
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - Default batch fetch size: 1
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO  ASTQueryTranslatorFactory       - Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - Query language substitutions: {}
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - Second-level cache: enabled
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - Query cache: disabled
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - Statistics: disabled
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - Default entity-mode: pojo
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - Named query checking : enabled
INFO  SettingsFactory                 - Check Nullability in Core (should be disabled when Bean Validation is on): disabled
INFO  SessionFactoryImpl              - building session factory
INFO  BasicTypeRegistry               - Type registration [materialized_blob] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.MaterializedBlobType@1a11d34
INFO  SessionFactoryObjectFactory     - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
INFO  SchemaUpdate                    - Running hbm2ddl schema update
INFO  SchemaUpdate                    - fetching database metadata
ERROR SchemaUpdate                    - could not get database metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot set auto commit to "true" when in distributed transaction.
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTSConnection.setAutoCommit(JTSConnection.java:625)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:60)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:168)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:375)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872)
```

What is your idea about this exception?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the clue is in

```
INFO  SessionFactoryObjectFactory - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
```

From the hibernate [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html):

> 3.8.2. JNDI-bound SessionFactory
>
> A JNDI-bound Hibernate SessionFactory can simplify the lookup function
>   of the factory and create new Sessions. This is not, however, related
>   to a JNDI bound Datasource; both simply use the same registry.
>
> If you wish to have the SessionFactory bound to a JNDI namespace,
>   specify a name (e.g. java:hibernate/SessionFactory) using the property
>   hibernate.session_factory_name. If this property is omitted, the
>   SessionFactory will not be bound to JNDI. This is especially useful in
>   environments with a read-only JNDI default implementation (in Tomcat,
>   for example).

So you'll need to provide a `hibernate.session_factory_name` in your hibernate config.

Comment: when I add <property name="hibernate.session_factory_name" value="java:hibernate/SessionFactory"/>, it says javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: createSubcontext not allowed in a ReadOnlyContext; remaining name '/hibernate'

Comment: I don't know much about Weblogic but this sounds like a Weblogic configuration issue to me insomuch as your app is not allowed to create the hibernate entry in the java: space.  I would try other names.

Comment: On `hibernate.session_factory_name` try it as given at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665086/how-to-access-sessionfactory-of-hibernate-using-jndi-in-weblogic-9-2-server/1665191#1665191